# Scrollable layout overlaps views

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

Can I set scrollable layout only when soft keyboard overlaps some views? I can detect if keyboard is visible, but can I detect if some views are overlapped and only then set it to scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to deal with ScrollView. You can use      `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the Activity tag of your Manifest to automatically adjust without using scrollview.

Comment: My case was specific, so it is not the case. But anyway I accept your answer because I think it is the right way how to deal it.